# FILESTREAM in SQL Server 2008 cannot be used on FAT systems?

Tags: sql-server, filestream, ntfs, fat

According to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

the FILESTREAM type is used for NTFS systems.  Does that mean it can't be used on FAT systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it means it can't be used on a system drive that is FAT.  It must be used on a drive that is NTFS or you will get an error like this:

> Msg 5134, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> The path that is specified by 'Z:\FATFormatted\yourfile.jpg' cannot be used for
>   FILESTREAM files because it is not on a supported file system.

Answer (score 1):

Let me forumlate it nicely:

There is not a single reason on this planet to ever use FAT for that. How can such a question ever come up?

FAT is unsafe, prone to corruption, does not support metadata / streams and in general is not recommended for anything than transportable items - such as SSD cards because most for example cameras suport FAT only.

SQL Server databases are high performance and I Can not imagine why anyone would like to have any item on a FAT partition for a server. MS thinks the same. And no, removable media are a terrible location for a SQL Server database part.

And yes, NTFS requirement OBVIOUSLY means no FAT.

Comment: You can format USB and external devices with NTFS if you want of course. Maybe OP want to run a database off such device [/shudders]

Comment: Yeah. Firing level offense for a database admin. OUCH.

Comment: I may wish to install SQL Server on some old computers running XP Home or the like, which may still have a FAT file system.

Comment: Ah - no. XP home for a SQL Server? May I laugh all the way to my work (just getting out)? Whoever decided to install XP home on a FAT partition... just deserves an award for clueless user. Really. FAT should not have been used in any system partition for ages.